# Why is validation loss BETTER than training loss for MNIST Digit Data?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, loss-function, mnist

We have implemented a simple fully connected neural network with KERAS for MNIST Digit recognition (60'000 training images 28x28pixes). For validation we create a random split with 10% of the training data. This yields the following plot:

[Training and Validation Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDz2G.png)

This is contrary to what we expected: why is the validation loss in the first epochs BETTER than training loss?

There are some standard reasons for validation loss better than training loss, which - as far as we understand - do not apply here:

- Dropout: We are not using any dropout (see code below)
- Training loss is calculated while not all data of an epoch was seen: this does not explain why training loss for epoch 2 (0.29) is worse than validation loss after epoch 1 (0.26)
- (Bad) luck with selection of validation set: we tried different sets and had same behaviour

Here's the corresponding code:

`

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import keras

RANDOM_SEED = 0xdeadbeef

from keras.datasets import mnist

# download official train and test sets
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

# the original image data are 8bit integers, we normalize them to floats in [0., 1.]
x_train = x_train.astype('float32') / 255
x_test = x_test.astype('float32') / 255


y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

print("train samples: ", x_train.shape[0])
print("test samples: ", x_test.shape[0])

print("shape of one sample: ", x_train[0].shape)



# define a simple feed-forward neural network.

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Flatten, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=(28, 28)))  # define input shape, here 28x28 images
model.add(Flatten())              # flatten 28x28 images to 784-dimensional vectors
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))    # hidden layer with 128 nodes and relu activation
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))  # output layer with 10 nodes (for 10 classes) and softmax activation

model.summary()

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="sgd", metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit(
  x_train,
  y_train,
  batch_size=16,
  epochs=40,
  validation_split=.1,
)

# helper function to plot the training and validation losses.

def plot_history(history: keras.callbacks.History):
 
  n = len(history.history['loss'])
  plt.plot(np.arange(n), history.history['loss'], label="training loss")
  plt.plot(np.arange(n), history.history['val_loss'], label="validation loss")
  plt.xticks(range(0, n + 1, 2))
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()


plot_history(history)
```

`

Comment: From time to time a batch-step update can make a model much worse, especially in the first epochs. Which would be reflected in the training loss but not in the validation loss

Comment: That is true - but i think here it must be something else, since the validation loss looks "to good to be true".

Answer (score 0):

So most of the time three thing could be the cause (or a combination of them):

1. `Regularization` is applied during training and not validation
2. `Train_Loss` is measured during epoch, `val_loss` after epoch
3. Validation set is "easier" then training set

I think we can for now assume, that `#3` is not a concern.
This leaves us with `#1` and `#2` that we have to take a look at.
Let's start with `#2`. To see if this is the main source of the diffrence of `val_loss` to `train_loss` we can shift the the train_loss by 0.5 epochs:

```
def plot_history_halfstep(history: keras.callbacks.History):
 
  n = len(history.history['loss'])
  plt.plot(np.arange(n)-0.5, history.history['loss'], label="training loss")
  plt.plot(np.arange(n), history.history['val_loss'], label="validation loss")
  plt.xticks(range(0, n + 1, 2))
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()
```

This gives us a improvement (second graph is shifted by 0.5).

[image]

Now let's look at `#1` regularization. Regularization is not only Dropout, but also such things as weigh decay and model capacity. When I remember correctly `sgd` does not have weight decay (e.g. `adam` does, you can see in just sswitching the optimizer you can get quite diffrent results), but you are having a really shallow model. When we add a few layers (e.g. two more dense layers) the things now look a little diffrent:

[image]

Combine this with the batch-step update the gap between `train_loss` and `val_loss` are now closer.

A very indept articel about this topic can be found [here](https://pyimagesearch.com/2019/10/14/why-is-my-validation-loss-lower-than-my-training-loss/).

Comment: Dear Fabian 
Thanks for the elaborate answer. I think the shift by 0.5 epochs is a good idea.

Comment: Hi Marc, if my answer solved your problem, I would appreciate it if you set it as accepted answer, so others can easily find the correct answer if they have the same question :)